# preventDefault doesn't work on some links

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I've been writing an extension that disables links on pages through the following code:

```
$('a[href]').each(function() {

            $(this).on('click.kill', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        })
```

However, on certain websites i.e. news.yahoo.com, some of the links remain active after the above script has run (for example, the "Get new Yahoo! Mail apps" link at the very top). What are possible reasons that cause this to occur? (90+% of links are disabled after the above code runs)

Edit:

As far as I know, the links exist before the script runs.

Comment: Do those links have `href` attributes? Do they have other event listeners attached to them?

Comment: The anchor may be generated after your script has run (use event delegation to fix this), or the event has been bound with the capture flag set to true & a `event.stopPropagation()` call.

Comment: @Blender Yes, they do have href attributes. How can I detect other event listeners?

Comment: If you don't need to navigate, you can remove href attribute from "a" tag. Please let us know if there any specific reason for this.

Comment: I don't think it's likely, but perhaps `return false` would be better. What if another event handler sees the click and does something in response?

Answer (score 1):

Are the links being added after your script runs? If so, you may need to do something like this:

```
$("body").on(
    "click.kill",
    "a[href]",
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);
```